# Spring HTTP File Upload: Validation of File Size

Tags: java, spring, file-upload

I've a basic question about validation of file size in a Spring based HTTP File Upload Service. I am using Spring's `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` to perform the file upload.

My question is does `multipartFile.getSize()` method return size only after completion of entire upload? If yes, what's the right look ahead approach to restrict files based on size?

> Note: The reason I ask this question is because I do not want an end user to upload 1 GB file and get an error message after
>   an hour saying, "Sorry, maximum file size allowed is 2 KB."

Answer (score 3):

Answer to your first question,is does multipartFile.getSize() method return size only after completion of entire upload?

-No,you get multipartFile.getSize() before  completion of entire upload.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/CSVfileupload")
public @ResponseBody String callCSVFileUpload(
    @RequestParam("CSVfilepath") MultipartFile multipartFile, HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
     //get the file size before doing any operation 
     logger.info("Controller - callCSVFileUpload() multipartFile.getSize()="+ multipartFile.getSize());
     InputStream inputStream =  new BufferedInputStream(multipartFile.getInputStream());
     JsonArray response=null;
     try{
         //you business logic 
        }
     catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        logger.info(" response.toString()="+ response.toString());
        return response.toString();
    }//end of callCSVFileUpload
```

You can use CommonsMultipartResolver in you application-context.xml file.

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="50000000" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Does this validate size before file transfer from client to server?

Comment: No.If you want to validate size before file transfer from client to server,you have use jquery/javascript validation.

Answer (score 1):

`MultipartFile` only check the file size in server side. if you want to check the file size at the time of upload you need to use client side `javascript` or `jquery`. `javascript` or `jquery` can be use to check the file side at the time of upload.

```
$('#myFile').bind('change', function() {

  //this.files[0].size gets the size of your file.
  alert(this.files[0].size);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the person do with it should be the front end programmer (javascript/h5) who should check the size before user uploading. Then the server side operator need to set some properties like
 "maxRequestLength" or "upload_max_filesize" for http request.

Comment: What if it is a REST API?